# Calling similar superclass and subclass methods at the same time

Tags: java

I'm making a program where I have a Person subclass and an Animal superclass. I'm wondering what's the best way of calling a similar method in both at the same time.
For instance, one way to do this would be:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public void walk() {
        // Do stuff
        childWalk();
    }
    public abstract void childWalk();
}
public class Person extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void childWalk() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

This way, I could call person.walk() and have both the child and parent methods called one after another, running the code in both.
Another way I have considered is:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public void walk() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
public class Person extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void walk() {
        super.walk();
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Which seems to be nicer, still calling person.walk() however it's still not ideal, and I can't help but feel that there's a more efficient way of doing this that I've not thought of. It feels wrong to have it up to the child class as to whether the parent class's method is called. (Animal.walk() should always be called no matter what)
Perhaps I'm going about it in the wrong way, and I don't actually need to do this at all? The reason I want to be able to do this is because every Animal needs to do things when it walks, but sometimes a Person wants to add to this behavior, perhaps incrementing a variable for every step, or something.

Perhaps this question is silly, but I've been googling for a while and see no easy answers.

Comment: If there is something that should be done and not overridden, then your first example is the correct one (though the `childWalk` should probably be `protected` rather than `public` and `walk` be `final`). If it's optional, then the second method is the correct one. Not sure what is bothering you exactly.

Comment: If the superclass and the subclass walk the exact same way, there's no need to override the walk method. If they share common characteristics, you want to place them in the superclass, and then for Person, call super.walk() as you've done, changing what you need within the subclass method.

Comment: I simply felt that the first method was a bit silly; to have to create a whole new abstract method just to get a walk() call down to your child feels odd. it would be nice if there was a way for a child to 'expand' on an existing parent's method without having to go into the parent and explicitly allow it.

Comment: There is no way to do that: if you had a marker that says whether the method can be overridden or just extended, the parent would still need to explicitly use that marker.

Comment: Good point. How would I handle a situation such as this if I wanted childWalk() to be optional for the subclass? Do I have to have a blank method in every child that doesn't want to use it, or is there a better way? In fact, now that I think about it, that's the problem I have with both of my methods. I'm really looking for a way to make the method optional for the child.

Comment: No, you put a blank method in the parent, instead of making it abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to make `walk()` final, and have it call an abstract method. So,

```
abstract class Animal {
  public final void walk() {
    // do stuff
    moreWalking();
  }

  protected abstract void moreWalking();
}
class Person extends Animal {
  protected void moreWalking() {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Notice that I made `moreWalking` use a protected level accessor (not public or private), so that it's overridable in derived classes, but can't be called by clients.

Also, this code is a 'sketch', I've left out lots of important things, like the interface for Animal that Davidxx talks about in his answer.

Once consequence of this is that subclasses of Animal 'must' implement `moreWalking()`. This can be mitigated by having a default implementation in a base class, or by not having the method abstract and providing an 'empty' implementation, like this:

```
abstract class Animal {
    public final void walk() {
        // do stuff
        moreWalking();
    }

    protected void moreWalking() {

    }
}
class Person extends Animal {
    protected void moreWalking() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    // No need to implement moreWalking
}
```

This means that you can always call `walk()` on any animal, be they person or dog, but that person will have some extra stuff that a dog doesn't have. I've kept `Animal` abstract because you won't want people creating an instance of it. If this isn't the case then you can remove that too.

Be aware though, we don't actually use subclasses this way very often in java. Typically we use interfaces and implementations, with subclasses to share common implementation (sometimes). This type of inheritance is quite difficult to understand and model, and it turns out that it's just not that useful. We usually come down to a rule called Liskov's Substitution Principle, which implies that subclassing is only useful if we're planning to make use of polymorphism -- which basically boils down to having collections of the supertype populated with instances of many subtypes upon which we wish to iterate and call the same method (this is quite a rough description of it).

Comment: `protected abstract void moreWalking() {
  }` doesn't compile. An abstract method  cannot have a body.

Answer (score -1):

Both ways are fine. Your second version (`super.walk()`) is the one most people would prefer, myself included. That is, assuming you do not have some special reason to do otherwise.

It actually makes sense for a child class to call an overridden method `f` as `super.f` in cases where the parent's behavior is to be preserved.  Two notes here: 1) To put your mind at ease, don't think of it as "leaving it up to the child" as much as it is the child saying "I really don't know for sure, so I'll defer to my parent," and you end up having the `super.f` call in *all* subclasses - might seem light a tiny, annoying, extra maintenance requirement, but it works. 2) You actually should *want* to have the flexibility of the child deciding if it will defer to the parent, because you very well may find some day that you create some oddball case of a child that actually does not want to use the parent's version at all.

I have lost count of the number of times that someone thought they were clever by completely hiding some functionality of a class through [black magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_(programming)) and left no way to break out of the paradigm that they set up. This only causes headaches. Some day someone will want to create a `Platypus` child class to your `Animal` base class, and their child class will *need* to do some weird things since it does not follow the rules for its animal family. That person (which might be you, kicking yourself in the future) might want to call `walk()` *without* calling `super.walk()`

One more important note: Sometimes you need to use the format that you used in your first example: `walk()` and `childWalk()`. One such common example is when the parent's behavior needs to extend both before and after the child's behavior. Then you might need something like:

```
class Animal {
    void walk() {
        stuff();
        childWalk();
        moreStuff();
    }
}
```

Usually you should not need that situation. If you run into that, give it a minute of thought to ask yourself if you actually do need it or if you can avoid that requirement, but sometimes it is necessary. I sometimes run into this problem and need to use this pattern when dealing with simulations where there is a need to preserve certain elements and order of operations of cause/effect scenarios, for example.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? I don't notice anything downvote-worthy.